# RowCount(LookupRows()) return 1 when I got more field matching the criteria in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to generate a unique order ID based on 3 criteria :

- product specific string "ABCDE"
- "MMdd" formatted timestamp "1127"
- order number from that day in "001" format

The way I'm trying to solve this is to do a LookupRows on the existing order IDs which contain the concatenation of the string and timestamp (e.g "ABCDE1127") and I increment the number it returns by 1 before appending said number to the end of my concatenated string (e.g first order of the day should be "ABCDE1127001").

I got 2 records in my data extension which match the value yet when I display the @rowcount value which should be 2 it returns 1...

Here is my code :

```
var @daystamp, @rowcount, @concatstamp, @dailyrowcount, @orderid

set @daystamp = Format(Now(), "MMdd")
set @concatstamp = Concat("ABCDE", @daystamp)
set @rowcount = RowCount(LookupRows("DataExtension", "OrderID", @concatstamp))
set @dailyrowcount = Format(Add(1, @rowcount), "000")
set @orderid = Concat("ABCDE", @daystamp, @dailyrowcount)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some details about what's in "DataExtension"?

Comment: What's the context of this code?  An email, landing page or SMS message?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier simply populate a data extension with a huge number of unique order IDs and then utilize the [**claimRowValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/claimrowvalue.htm) to reserve a number for each email:

The **OrderNums** Data Extension would have these columns:

- **OrderNum**, String (50), Primary Key, non-nullable
- **IsClaimed**, Boolean, nullable
- **EmailAddress**, EmailAddress, nullable
- **ClaimedDate**, Date, nullable

The email would include code something like this:

```
%%[

var @emailAddress, @defaultOrderNum, @orderNum

set @defaultOrderNum = "X"
set @emailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @orderNum = ClaimRowValue("orderNums", "orderNum", "IsClaimed", @defaultOrderNum, "EmailAddress", @emailAddress)

if @orderNum == "X" then
  raiseerror("no more order numbers")
endif

]%%

Order Num: %%=v(@orderNum)=%%
```